# Why do Wizards look like this?

Tags: magical-creatures, wizards

If I hear the word "magician" I think most immediately of an old man in a dark robe.
He wears a pointy hat. Sometimes with stars and moons.

Also this is what you get when you type "wizard" into your favorite web search enige.

What is the origin of this representation?

Comment: See http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/39268/4918 "Why do fantasy writers depict pointy hats as the headgear of choice for Witches and Wizards?" about the origins of the trope.

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/81715/did-tolkien-popularize-the-generic-description-of-a-wizard prob a dupe of this, as the answer states the norse god Odin is the most likely candidate for this trope